# Как работать с графикой на windows

Tags: winapi, графика, directx, движок

Как работать с графикой на низком уровне?
Разработка под виндовс и графика 2д.

Какие библиотеки используются для работы с графикой?
Можно ли без библиотек работать с графикой?

Comment: На самом деле тут палка с палками без концов, внутри друг друга. Что бы пройти тот же путь что проходили разработчики 90 - 00х нужно пройти путь разработчиков 80х(mario и тд). А ведь именно в начале 90х мир колыхнуло от революции в мире шутеров ^^ это я про Doom 1(93), а в 98 - уже half-life. И у той и у другой были свои движки :) При этом нужно понимать насколько ЭВМ - уже перестал быть только ЭВМ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня не достаточно репутации чтобы написать комментарий поэтому напишу как ответ.

Используйте Opengl winapi(или OpenGL и GLFW) или вместо OPENGL Directx, но  Opengl  лучше, directx только под винду.

Comment: Оформить бы получше и можно было бы считать нормальным ответом, что проще найти уроки по OpenGL и изучить их. Уроки по DirectX тоже есть, но их я встречал в меньшей степени.

Comment: Да у Directx с этим проблема...